# Using helm to create a file while in a helm session

Tags: helm, find-file

I often find myself in a command that queries for a filename e.g. `diff-tell-file-name`. This command asks me what file to apply a diff to.

In my case, often the file does not exist and I would like to create it. `helm-find-file` allows for creating new files just by typing in their name. However lots of helmified commands DO NOT allow you to do so and just echoes the error: `[No match]`

I would want to run `helm-find-file` while inside the minibuffer prompt but that apparently is not allowed and gives the error `helm: Error: Trying to run helm within a running helm session`.

Is there a way to "suspend" a query and then get back to it? 
Is there a way to modify or advise a helmified command to allow it to accept non-existent files create them on the go.

I feel I am missing how to effectively use helm. Thanks